# Show the subcategories of the chosen category in Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, coffeescript

**1. In my **view/gigs/new.html.erb** i use

```
 <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "Choose a category"} %>
 <%= f.collection_select :subcategory_id, Subcategory.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "Choose a subcategory"} %>
```

It creates this

[image: dropdown category and subcategory]

and when clicked the below image:

[image: the dropdown categories and subcategories]

From the picture above as you see depending on what category i choose,just the subcategories owned by that category are displayed.

**2.** In my gig controller for this to work,i wrote the below code.

```
def update_sub_categories
  @cats = Subcategory.where(category_id: params[:category_id]).all
  respond_with(@cats)
end
```

**3.** I had to create a file in the same folder **view/gigs/update_sub_categories**
and put this code

```
$("#gig_subcategory_id").empty().append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "subcategory", :collection => @cats, :as => :cat)) %>")
```

Also the partial in the same folder v**iew/gigs/_subcategory.html.erb**

```
<option value="<%= cat.id %>"><%= cat.name %></option>
```

**4.** Add in **App/javascript/gigs.js.coffee**

```
  $(document).on 'change', '#gig_category_id', (evt) ->
    $.ajax 'update_sub_categories',
      type: 'GET'
      dataType: 'script'
      data: {
        category_id: $("#gig_category_id option:selected").val()
      }
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        console.log("Dynamic country select OK!")
```

**5.** Finally in **routes**

```
get 'gigs/update_sub_categories' => 'gigs#update_sub_categories'
```

> **Question:** Everything works, i choose the category and the subcategory of the chosen category appear.But it works just in
>   **views/gigs/new.html.erb**,and doesn't in **views/gigs/edit.html.erb**, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does your `edit.html.erb` contain? and what do you mean by doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in your console or development.log and you're going to see some message indicating that rails could not resolve `update_sub_categories` when your script fails. Wheras when calling that method with a new form, you'll see that rails is calling `your_controller/your_action/update_sub_categories` -- you can probably see where this is going now.

You're going to have to update your `routes.rb` both to handle a "naked" call to the method (when it's missing `your_action` and for member routing. Explicit handling of member routing is necessary because your edit uses an `ID` field embedded in the route, rather than appending it at the end.

Replace your current routing in `routes.rb` with the following and you should be in good shape:

```
  get 'update_sub_categories' => 'your_model#update_sub_categories'

  get 'your_model/update_sub_categories' => 'your_model#update_sub_categories'

  resources :your_model do
    get :update_sub_categories, :on => :member
  end
```

Obviously, you're going to want to substitute your model name for the string `your_model` in my example.