# Assign Subcategories to a Main Category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

On my current local blog site I'm able to create both Categories and Subcategories.

I want to make is so when creating a post, once you choose the category from the drop-down, it will only show the available subcategories.

**Example:**

[image]

In this example "News is selected". So I need to do two things. First, assign the subcategories I make to specific categories. Second, display the subcategories accordingly depending on which category is chosen.

**Post Model**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :subcategory
  has_many :comments

end
```

**New Post View**

```
<h2>Add New Post</h2>

<div class="well">
<%= form_for [:admin, @post] do |f| %>

    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :title %>
        <%= f.text_field :title ,class:'form-control' %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :category %>
        <%= f.select :category_id, Category.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {:include_blank => 'Select One'},class:'form-control' %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :image %>
        <%= f.file_field :image %>  
    </div>
    <br>

    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :subcategory %>
        <%= f.select :subcategory_id, Subcategory.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {:include_blank => 'Select One'},class:'form-control' %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :body %>
        <%= f.text_area :body ,class:'form-control', id:'eg-textarea' %>
    </div>
    <br>
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class:'btn btn-primary' %>
    <%=link_to "Cancel", admin_posts_path, class:'btn btn-default' %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

**Posts Controller**

```
class Admin::PostsController < Admin::ApplicationController
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.save
    redirect_to admin_posts_path
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :category_id, :subcategory_id, :image, :body)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with AJAX; see: [Show the subcategories of the chosen category in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30548453/show-the-subcategories-of-the-chosen-category-in-rails-4).

You could also put all of the subcategories with their parent category IDs as an array of objects in `admin/posts.coffee.erb`. Then, on the category select field's `change` event, [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the list of subcategories by the selected category ID into a new array, then use jQuery to remove existing option tags in the subcategory field and add the option tags for the subcategories to the subcategory select field.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a hidden form up above. This prevents the need for AJAX and special routes. Use JavaScript/jQuery to pull the subcategories from the hidden form into the main form. The `populatesubs` function I've written in here does just that.

Perhaps something like this would work (if anything is wrong, check the DOM element IDs):

```
<h2>Add New Post</h2>

<!-- The hidden form -->
<div style="display: none;">
  <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
    <%= select_tag :subcategory, options_for_select(category.subcategories.collect { |s| [s.name, s.id] }), id: "subcategory#{category.id}" %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // Change the subcategories form to have the subcategories of the selected category
  function populatesubs(category)
  {
    subcategory = '#subcategory' + category
    $('#post_subcategory_id').html($(subcategory).html());
  }
</script>



<div class="well">
<%= form_for [:admin, @post] do |f| %>

    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :title %>
        <%= f.text_field :title ,class:'form-control' %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :category %>
        <%= f.select :category_id, Category.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {:include_blank => 'Select One'}, class: 'form-control', onchange: 'populatesubs(this.value)' %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :image %>
        <%= f.file_field :image %>  
    </div>
    <br>

    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :subcategory %>
        <%= f.select :subcategory_id, Category.all.first.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {:include_blank => 'Select One'},class:'form-control' %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :body %>
        <%= f.text_area :body ,class:'form-control', id:'eg-textarea' %>
    </div>
    <br>
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class:'btn btn-primary' %>
    <%=link_to "Cancel", admin_posts_path, class:'btn btn-default' %>
<% end %>
</div>
```